# Attaching climbing holds on a rock surface

Tags: adhesive, stone, granite

I have a set of climbing holds that I would like to attach to a stone finished outside wall of a house.

It's a granite rock that I would be attaching the holds to, like this:

My preference is to avoid drilling into the wall, and I would rather glue the holds.

Could epoxy glue be a good choice for such project?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to avoid drilling?

Comment: Do you know whether or not the stones are just thin decorative pieces affixed to a wall, or whether those are actual stones that **are** the wall?

Comment: I wouldn't trust climbing rocks only attached by glue, more than likely one will pop off at an inconvenient time and then someone gets hurt

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the best plan.  Those flagstones are attached in such a way as to support themselves with the primary force acting on them being gravity with a force direction of straight down.  If you attach climbing holds you are introducing a new element here which is an outward force that wants to pull the stone off the face of the wall.  It's anyone's guess in my mind as to whether or not this installation of stones was done with that use in mind.  My guess is that the answer is NO and you should come up with a different plan.

Comment: @depperm True, but that is also a risk when climbing on natural rock face's of mountains and i would think  it an integral componate of the adrenaline rush associated with rock climbing.

Comment: @AlaskaMan if they really want adrenaline and the risk of climbing: don't use climbing holds or climb the stone face. I'd think the climbing molds (probably at home) would be there to reduce risk and be 'safer' than normal rock climbing

Comment: @AlaskaMan a fall never hurt anyone, just stopping at the end.

Comment: as a child I free climbed a retaining wall made from random rocks similar to those pictured, this was possible because there was less mortar in the joins.

Comment: The stones are not the wall, there's a brick wall that supports the structure on the inner side. However, it's true that the outer wall has not been designed with outward force in mind and it's valid point. 
I'm a little concerned, perhaps, that with drilling I could introduce water inside which could become an issue if it freezes. Perhaps there are ways to avoid that.
The holds would basically at the ground level, with the purpose to traverse the wall sideways, rather than climb up, so risk of injury would be rather low.